# Counting punctuation in text using Python and regex

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I am trying to count the number of times punctuation characters appear in a novel. For example, I want to find the occurrences of question marks and periods along with all the other non alphanumeric characters. Then I want to insert them into a csv file. I am not sure how to do the regex because I don't have that much experience with python. Can someone help me out?

```
texts=string.punctuation
counts=dict(Counter(w.lower() for w in re.findall(r"\w+", open(cwd+"/"+book).read())))
writer = csv.writer(open("author.csv", 'a'))
writer.writerow([counts.get(fieldname,0) for fieldname in texts])
```

Comment: Don't do frequency counting with regex. Just loop character by character and filter out letters, digits and spaces, and push the rest into a dict for frequency counting. Or another way is to replace all letters, digits and spaces, then loop through the remaining string (which is cleaner).

Comment: You are defeating the purpose of a Counter by down-initialising it into a dictionary and then calling `.get(x, 0)` when you could have just left it as a counter, which returns 0 for missing items

Comment: you don't need regex at all, just check if the character is `in` the [string module's punctuation string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) when iterating through the novel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [1]: from string import punctuation

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: counts = Counter(open('novel.txt').read())

In [4]: punctuation_counts = {k:v for k, v in counts.iteritems() if k in punctuation}
```

Comment: The only real problem I have with this is that you load the whole novel into memory at once!!! `open('novel.txt').read()` I can imagine any averaged sized novel will make this quite a memory intensive operation.

Comment: @jamylak, the [entire King James bible](http://printkjv.ifbweb.com/#downloads) is only a few megabytes. (4.4MB when unzipped).

Answer (score 4):

```
from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter

with open('novel.txt') as f: # closes the file for you which is important!
    c = Counter(c for line in f for c in line if c in punctuation)
```

This also avoids loading the whole novel into memory at once.

Btw this is what `string.punctuation` looks like:

```
>>> punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

You may want to add or detract symbols from here depending on your needs.

Also `Counter` defines a `__missing__` with simply does `return 0`. So instead of down-initialising it into a dictionary and then calling `.get(x, 0)`. Just leave it as a counter and access it like `c[x]`, if it doesn't exist, its count is 0. I'm not sure why everybody has the sudden urge to downgrade all their `Counter`s into `dict`s just because of the scary looking `Counter([...])` you see when you print one, when in fact `Counter`s are dictionaries too and deserve respect.

```
writer.writerow([counts.get(c, 0) for c in punctuation])
```

If you leave your counter you can just do this:

```
writer.writerow([counts[c] for c in punctuation])
```

and that was much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def count_puncts(x):
  # sub. punct. with '' and returns the new string with the no. of replacements.
  new_str, count = re.subn(r'\W', '', x)
  return count
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is very close to what you'd need if you were counting words. If you were trying to count words, the only modification you'd have to make would probably be to change the last line to this:

```
writer.writerows(counts.items())
```

Unfortunately, you're not trying to count words here. If you're looking for counts of single characters, I'd avoid using regular expressions and go straight to `count`. Your code might look like this:

```
book_text = open(cwd+"/"+book).read()
counts = {}
for character in texts:
    counts[character] = book_text.count(character)
writer.writerows(counts.items())
```

As you might be able to tell, this makes a dictionary with the characters as keys and the number of times that character appears in the text as the value. Then we write it as we would have done for counting words.

Answer (score 0):

Using curses:

```
import curses.ascii
str1 = "real, and? or, and? what."
t = (c for c in str1 if curses.ascii.ispunct(c))
d = dict()
for p in t:
    d[p] = 1 if not p in d else d[p] + 1 for p in t
```

Comment: There's no need for that `for` loop; just use `d = Counter(t)`. Furthermore, you could use `map` rather than that generator expression, although that might not be quite so obvious.

Comment: Try and avoid using `str` as a variable name, since you might need to use `str(1)` later in your program and now you can't